# Refreshing two DIVs at the same time with one PHP script & jQuery load

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

What i am trying to do is: 1)Show a live time count of the last backup taken in one DIV 
               2)Change the colour of another DIV as time passes and also the text in it

How I am trying to do: By refreshing the elements using Jquery load.

Success till now: I have been successful in displaying the time count but cannot understand how to change the text and colour of the other DIV.

I was thinking if somehow it was possible to pass the colour value from the script in each load then it might work but am not sure whether my approach and my thoughts to the task is proper.
I looked all over the web but nothing came in handy.

I would really appreciate some help.
Improvements to the code is also welcome. :)

Thanking in advance..

PHP

```
<?php
$dir="DB_Backups/";
$file= array();
$file = scandir($dir, 1);
if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file)
    continue;
$newest_file=$dir.$file[0];
if(is_file($newest_file)){

$time=time()-filemtime($newest_file);

if($time<2){
    echo "Last Backup just now";
}

if($time>=2 && $time<60){
    echo "Last Backup few seconds ago";
}
else
if($time>=60 && $time<2*60){
echo "Last Backup a minute ago";
}
else
if($time>=2*60 && $time<3600){
    echo "Last Backup few minutes ago";
}
else
if($time>=3600 && $time<2*3600){
    echo "Last Backup an hour ago";
}
else
if($time>=2*3600 && $time<86400){
    echo "Last Backup few hours ago";
}
else
if($time>86400){
    echo "Last Backup on ".date("F d, Y",filemtime($newest_file));
}
}
else{
    echo "Backup not yet performed!";
}
?>
```

JQuery

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#status").load("f_backupstatus.php");

    },1000);
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="test" style="background-color: #0066CC;">
<span id="status" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></span></div>
<div id="colour" style="background-color: #999999">colour</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always return a JSON object. In the PHP file, it would probably be a good idea to have an array with responses and colors:


**PHP:**

```
<?php
$dir = "DB_Backups/";
$file = array();
$file = scandir($dir, 1);
$newest_file = $dir.$file[0];
$responses = array(
    ['status' => 'Last Backup just now', 'colour' => 'green'],
    ['status' => 'Last Backup a few seconds ago', 'colour' => 'blue'],
    ['status' => 'Last Backup a minute ago', 'colour' => 'violet'],
    ['status' => 'Last Backup a few minutes ago', 'colour' => 'yellow'],
    ['status' => 'Last Backup on'.date("F d, Y", filemtime($newest_file)), 'colour' => 'orange'],
    ['status' => 'Backup not performed yet!', 'colour' => 'red'],
);

if(is_file($newest_file)) {
    $time=time()-filemtime($newest_file);
}

if ($time > 86400) {
    $return = $responses[5];
} else if ($time > 7200) {
    $return = $responses[4];
} else if ($time > 3600) {
    $return = $responses[3];
} else if ($time > 120) {
    $return = $responses[2];
} else if ($time > 60) {
    $return = $responses[1];
} else {
    $return = $responses[0];
}

return json_encode($return);
?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    setInverval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'f_backupstatus.php',
            success: function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#status').text(data['status']);
                $('#colour').css('background-color', data['colour'])
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}):
```

Comment: dont we need to set a time interval for the refresh?

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct sir. My answer has been updated.

Comment: dont know why but no output is being displayed :(

Comment: Add `error: function() { alert("didn't work") }`. If you don't get a response, that will get called. Should that be the case, wrap your php in a `try catch` that echoes the error message. Also, `alert(data)` in the success function.  I'd love to help, but I need an error first.

Comment: I think perhaps each array contained in $responses array should be placed in a wrapper object in order to prevent JSON hijacking. A json array should never be returned as is for a GET request

Comment: @scheisse_minelli, i added the error function but still no output, not even error alert.

Comment: okay, i think i have the problem now. Its not with the jquery part. Its the php. I am using php 5.3 and it doesn't support object dereferencing which is supported from 5.4 hence I get a parse error.
can you show me a workaround with the array part so that it can be done in 5.3?

Comment: A little tweak to the array part and its working :) Thank you.